# Lights shadow looks odd

Tags: light, shadows

I once again am in need of some help. I am using a spot light to light the side of a ship because I will be using a mask to have a digital display of a phone. The light looks extremely odd and speckled making it look a tad unrealistic. Is there a way to alter this ? Please see photo for reference, thank you in advance! [image]

Comment: Guessing: either the light's too small (default is 0.1) or you don't have enough samples. To be more precise, we need more information (again)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I changed the size of the light and it was immediately rectified.